# Asp.net (VB.net) MVC passing modified model back to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I am trying to bind a list of models to controls then send the modified values back to another controller but when i post back the parameters list on my Parameters model is empty.

Model

```
Public Class Parameters

    Public Property Parameters As New List(Of Parameter)

End Class
Public Class Parameter

    Public Property Label As String
    Public Property InventorParameter As String
    Public Property DataType As String
    Public Property ControlType As String
    Public Property DefaultValue As String
    Public Property MultiValueList As String
    Public Property BooleanValue As Boolean

End Class
```

View (Which displays fine with the correct values in the controls)

```
 <div id="parameter_form" class="container">
        
        @Using Html.BeginForm("Configure", "Home", FormMethod.Post)

            @For Each formParameter As Parameter In Model.Parameters

                @Html.Raw("<div class=""form-group"">")

                @Html.Label(formParameter.InventorParameter, formParameter.Label)
                If formParameter.ControlType = "textbox" Then
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) formParameter.DefaultValue, New With {.class = "form-control"})
                ElseIf formParameter.ControlType = "combobox" Then
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) formParameter.DefaultValue, New SelectList(formParameter.MultiValueList.Split("|").ToArray()), New With {.class = "form-control"})
                ElseIf formParameter.ControlType = "checkbox" Then
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(x) formParameter.BooleanValue, New With {.class = "checkbox"})
                End If

                @Html.Raw("</div>")

            Next

            @Html.Raw("<Button Class=""btn btn-primary"" input type=""submit"">Configure Product</button>")

        End Using
```

Controllers

```
 Function Index() As ActionResult

            'Get Parameters from Database
            Dim configConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLConnectionString").ConnectionString
            Dim SQL As New SqlHandler(configConnectionString)
            Return View(SQL.GetParameters(1, 1))

        End Function

        <HttpPost>
        Function Configure(Model As Parameters) As ActionResult

            'Get Parameters from Database
            Dim configConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLConnectionString").ConnectionString
            Return Nothing

        End Function
```

I think the way i'm binding may be wrong:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) formParameter.DefaultValue, New With {.class = "form-control"})
```

But when i try the below i get a syntax error

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.DefaultValue, New With {.class = "form-control"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: Adding @modeltype CadlineETO.Product to the top of my view and looping through like below worked.

@For i As Integer = 0 To Model.Parameters.Count - 1